# Create a new Ros Android application

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed  rosandroid (http://wiki.ros.org/android) and can run the sample applications/tutorials.
Now **I want to create a new Android Studio Project and develop my own app**. I found this tutorial [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-android-application), but it doesn't work.

I executed these commands:

```
roscd android_core
cp -a android_tutorial_pubsub my_package
```

and added `include "my_package"` to *android_core/settings.gradle*

But when i  run this command:

```
./gradlew my_package:clean my_package:debug
```

I get the following Error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/user/android_core/src/android_core/my_package/build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':my_package'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_tutorial_pubsub:[0.2,0.3)] on project ':my_package'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Can somebody help me or post another tuorial for creating a new Android Project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212153/create-a-new-ros-android-application/) by [mmore](https://answers.ros.org/users/22937/mmore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24801/leman/) on 2015-10-23**:
have you found a solution for this problem?

**Comment by [mmore](https://answers.ros.org/users/22937/mmore/) on 2015-10-23**:
Not really. But you could copy "android_tutorial_pubsub" in your file explorer and rename it to something like "android_myrosandroidapp" and add 'include "android_myrosandroidapp"' to android_core/settings.gradle . After this you have to remove the unnecessary files manually in your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the article ["Creating Android Packages" in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/Creating%20Android%20Packages) I found a solution:

```
catkin_create_android_pkg android_foo android_core rosjava_core std_msgs
cd android_foo
catkin_create_android_project -t 10 -p com.github.ros_java.android_foo.bar bar
cd ../.. ; catkin_make
```

Finally add the following line to your file `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_10:[0.2,0.3)'
}
```

---

Originally posted by [mmore](https://answers.ros.org/users/22937/mmore/) with karma: 51 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0